# How to get all data back in an ios parse query

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have two tables each with one record(for testing and question purposes). These tables are `Post` and `Comment`. `Post` has a `PFRelation` called `myComment` (I know only one comment - lets call it a feature for now). If I query `Post`, how do I get the `Post` and `Comment` data back?

Can't find this anywhere using web search engines or Parse docs (not a complete answer at least).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Relation` in Parse is just like its literal meaning, it does not contain any data. If you want to get the data back, you need to get that instance of `Relation` first. Then call `query` from that instance. After that, you just perform that query if you want to get all objects from this `Relation`. You can also add some constraints after getting the query from `Relation`.

If you use `Pointer` type, you can just get back the data by using `includeKey:`.

Comment: Finally what I wanted.  If I am return 20 records at a time and each has a 1 record pointer to another class, is includeKey better/less time then doing 20 internal queries?

Comment: Thanks for answering both of my SO questions

Comment: Pointer is used for one to one relationship. That's what I would think in your case.